# How to replace icon view with list view on an iPhone's home page?

Tags: iphone

I dislike selecting programs or other files from a grid of icons ("icon view"), even if their titles are shown beneath the icons. I prefer to select from a scrollable list of titles ("list view"), either with no icons present or if unavoidable then only with a very small icon at the start of each line.

Is there a way to make my iPhone XR (running iOS 13.3) use list view rather than icon view on its home page?

Answer (score 4):

No, not without any type of jailbreak.

Apple doesn't allow any changes to the default grid view of their iOS/iPadOS devices.

If you have a jailbroken device, you can use tweak like [HomeList](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/05/01/homelist/).  This adds watchOS-type scrolling to the home page.

[image]